# storing session data to mysql tables and last_insert_id function

Tags: php, mysql, session

When a nurse logs into the patient system, details about her are stored in session variables - including her user id. I have created a registration script so that when the nurse registers a new patient, her id is stored in the super column of the user table. This is so the patient can be allocated to her only.

The problem is that when I run the insert statement, the value 0 is stored in the super user column instead of the user id of the nurse. How can this be solved?

I have a profile table that has the profile of the user and it links to the user table. I have used the first insert statement to create the record in the user table. I want the second statement to create a record in the profile table with the profile id being the same as the newly created user_id. I am trying to use the `LAST_INSERT_ID()` function, but it too is storing 0 and not the last id.

Here is my code around the specific part in question. I am sorry if the formatting is not correct. I am using a screen reader and the formatting options on this website arn't very accessible to me.

I have stored the form data from $_post into all the variables used below.

```
$SuperUser = $_SESSION['SuperUser'];
//insert query for user table
$UserInsert = "insert into user
(User_id,
Username,
Password,
User_level,
SuperUser)
values(null,
'$Username',
'$Password',
'1',
'$SuperUser')";
//run query for inserting data for user table
mysql_query($UserInsert) or die("cannot insert into user");

//Select the last increment id from user table
$LastIdQuery = "Select LAST_INSERT_ID()";
$LastId = mysql_query($LastIdQuery) or die("Cannot select last id");

//insert query for profile table
$ProfileInsert = "insert into profile
(User_id,
FirstName,
LastName,
Dob,
NI_Number,
NHS_Number,
Address1,
Address2,
Town,
Postcode,
Email,
Contact_Number,
Comments)
values('$LastId',
'$FirstName',
'$LastName',
'$DobYear-$DobMonth-$DobDay',
'$NI_Number',
'$NHS_Number',
'$Address1',
'$Address2',
'$Town',
'$Postcode',
'$Email',
'$Contact_Number',
'$Comments')";
//insert into profile
mysql_query($ProfileInsert) or die("Unable to insert in profile");
mysql_close();
```

Answer (score 0):

Try doing `$id =  mysql_insert_id()` instead of the LAST_INSERT_ID function that you're doing. Also, if you're storing the mysql connection in a variable, passing it to `mysql_insert_id()` can make it more accurate. E.g when connecting to database:

```
$link = mysql_connect(......);
```

then later:

```
mysql_query($ProfileInsert) or die("Unable to insert in profile");
$id = mysql_insert_id( $link );
mysql_close( $link );
```

Comment: Could you please also try to help me with the session variable not inserting in the super user column? It is being stored correctly as i have printed it to test. Thank you

Comment: @ChamandeepSingh Don't know, check to make sure the id is an int, if its a string (i.e has anything except numbers) it will be stored as 0 if your db column is of int type. and click the checkbox to accept the answer

Comment: The user id that is stored in the session came from an int column from another table and it is also being put in another int type column. It is still being  output as 0.

Comment: Check if the variable is losing its value or being set to something else anywhere, you can put `echo $id` throughout your code to see where its value changes